# How the ARM template will authenticate to deploy resources into target server using CI / CD pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Will it take the logged-in user account or some other authentication using CI / CD pipeline

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the operations will run as the logged in user/service principal.

Comment: Is there any way we can change this and pass some other user/service principal credentials ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hoe to validate ARM template by passing credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646117/hoe-to-validate-arm-template-by-passing-credentials)

Answer (score 1):

Juunas is right, you typically create a **service principal** within Azure AD (instead of a user principal) and grant it **contributor** right to your subscription / resource group.

In Visual Studio Team Services you can add that principal as a *Service Endpoint* and when you add a Task within your Release build to deploy the template you can select that:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way we can change this and pass some other user/service principal credentials ?

Comment: You want to use a user principal instead of a service principal?